# Assets on subdomain

Tags: apache

I have created assets.domain.com to store all the css, js, images and videos for my projects

```
domain.com
app1.domain.com
app2.domain.com
```

It's working well. Is this a good practice as when i visit assets.domain.com i can see the below
[image]

Is there a way to hide them? I mean when someone visits assets.domain.com it should display nothing found here. But i can freely use http://assets.domain.com/css/app.css in my projects. Same for other js, images and video files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off indexes on option - see https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings